Parameter org.springframework.data.mapping.Parameter does not have a name - Spring boot 3.3.1
I've upgraded a Spring boot service from 2.5.9 to 3.3.1 and the below Errors occurs when a Rest End point which uses mongoTemplate.find() with a  Query.
    Exception in com.myApp.test.web.rest.myResource.getData() with cause = 'NULL' and exception = 'Parameter org.springframework.data.mapping.Parameter@5fc617e3 does not have a name'
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Parameter org.springframework.data.mapping.Parameter@5fc617e3 does not have a name
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:62)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ValueExpressionParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(ValueExpressionParameterValueProvider.java:56)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:98)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:536)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readDocument(MappingMongoConverter.java:504)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$DefaultConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:2399)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$ConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:2208)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1974)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:644)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.populateProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:561)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:538)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readDocument(MappingMongoConverter.java:504)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$DefaultConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:2399)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$ConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:2208)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readCollectionOrArray(MappingMongoConverter.java:1470)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$DefaultConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:2376)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$ConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:2208)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1974)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:644)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.populateProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:561)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:538)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readDocument(MappingMongoConverter.java:504)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:440)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:127)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDocumentCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:3293)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2927)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2604)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2583)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:868)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:858)

After searching for a while I found that 'Parameter org.springframework.data.mapping.Parameter@4520eec does not have a name' error is due to Spring removing Parameter Name retention. As their fix they have requested to add the following to POM and -parameter flag to javac. However I've done both and it doesn't seem to work.
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <parameters>true</parameters>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

I've then run mvn clean install and inspected the .class files with javap and all the methods do have their parameter names whether I keep the fix suggested by Spring or not.

I doubt it is complaining about the code shown here as there is no @Parameter or @Param in there. If you are using Spring Boot with maven the <parameter>true</parameter> is already added (assuming you are using the spring-boot-starter-parent as a parent in there.
